# What is the lldb equivalent for gdb load

Tags: rust, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to flash a binary to the STM32F303 MCU, the equivalent gdb command is "load", what is the equivalent command for lldb?

Answer (score 0):

```
target modules load --load --set-pc-to-entry --slide 0 --file <absolute path to binary>
```